# Filter excel data excluding the duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns of data, I want to exclude the duplicates and keep only one registry of each sort, how can I do that?

For example having this set of data:

[image: two columns]

filtering it and get:

[image: two columns filtered]

what is the filter I should use?

Comment: 1) What did you already try?  Where did you get stuck?
2) How often do you need to do that. For a once off job: concattenate both cells. Remove duplicates (via the ribbon). Split again.

Comment: @Hennes - Why concatenate to remove dupes?

Comment: Because I assume that we would not only have `a 1` and `a 1`, but also `a 2` and similar combinations. Even though the example shows only fixed combinations.  (also, not at a PC with excel atm, so I can not check if it removed duplicated from multiple colums, but I recall de-duping on a single column and I recall concat.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to filter out these duplicates might be to use two helper columns.

In the first helper column use a formula to concatenate the two cell values.
In another helper column count how often the concatenated value has appeared above the current row and flag the cell. Consider the screenshot:

[image]

The formula in C2 and copied down is

=A2&B2

The formula in D2 and copied down is

=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:C2,C2)>1,"","keep")

Now you can use a filter on column D and show only the rows with the value "keep".

Note: if you want to remove the duplicates altogether, you can use the Remove Duplicates command on the Data ribbon.  You don't need to concatenate anything. Just select a cell in the two columns, click Data > Remove Duplicates and make sure both columns are ticked in the list. Hit OK and the duplicates are gone.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to remove the duplicates. In that case, you would not use a filter, rather it is as simple as using the `Remove Duplicate` feature found on the Data tab.

Highlight the data, select the Data tab, click `Remove Duplicates`, click `OK`.

[image]

Will leave you with the results you are looking for in your example.

[image]